# cakephp 3.6 can't Display Image

Tags: css, image, cakephp

I have problem when I Try Display Image on my login page It doesn't appear

```
<?= $this->Html->image('crm.jpg', ['alt' => 'User image']); ?>
```

When I check the console on Chrome

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

When I try accessing http://localhost/intellix/img/crm.jpg it says 
Error: ImgController could not be found.

Which isn't needed.

crm.jpg is located in webroot/img/

Now the weird part if i change crm with another image name ex: silhouette.png it works fine but so far it only worked with this one

[image: Screenshot]
Any Ideas ?

(Note : Using Chrome Cakephp Sublime text Up to date)

Edit : I had the same problem trying to load CSS Scripts Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was indeed in access right in this file 
.htaccess inside webroot folder

There was this line which I added

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Restoring it to default Removing it did the trick

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your image `crm.jpg` does not exist. In this case, CakePHP is routing the request to ImgController. Is the image `silhouette.png` located in the same directory?

A second thing might be the access right. Maybe it is not readable? Check the access rights and make it at least readable for all.

Comment: I found the problem it was in .htaccess

Comment: There was  also some files I couldn't load Scripts and CSS